# Logging in to a oracle database through firefox plugin

Tags: java, xml, oracle, firefox-addon

I want to know is it possible to log in to an existing oracle database through firefox plugin?

Comment: You really need to provide more details of what you are trying to do and an explanation of why would more than likely would be helpful also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing specifically for Oracle.

However, there is an ODBC plug-in, ODBC Bridge for HTML5. This will allow you to build HTML5 apps which connect to any ODBC compliant database, including Oracle.  The plug-in page has lots of useful looking links.

You are, of course, restricted to using a later version of Firefox which supports the HTML5 standard. And you'll need ODBC drivers and to define an ODBC data source.

[Find out more](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/odbc-bridge-for-html5/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try my chances with the ODBC and post more about it later.